# Xcode 4 - created new target, got problems with duplicate interface declarations

Tags: xcode, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Xcode, and I'm working on my first project in this environment. I have come across a real head scratcher.

My project is soon ready to be launched. So I wanted to change the product name from a silly work name to the actual name of the soon to be launched product. So I created a new Target with the real name.

When I try to compile the new target I get like 90 errors telling me that I have duplicate interface declaration. All errors occurs in cocos2d framework header files, that I use for my game.

Obviously I missed out on something creating the new target.
My first thought was that there was some kind of conflict with the old target, so I deleted it. Which wasn't the smartest thing since I now can't compare the build settings between the two targets to see what went wrong.

Is there anyone out there who can enlighten a poor sod like myself on whats wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to change how the app is named in the App store and on devices.  You configure the app name in iTunes Conect, and to configure how the target appears on a device, go to Target > Info > Bundle Display name and change that to what you want to appear on a device.  Build and deploy, and you should see your results in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I can't even compile the target :(